# Code igniter large query results result_array() result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am looking at [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

I have queries that return up to 10,000 rows and usually fills up the memory

I am currently doing:

```
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Is there a way to not load all of the data into memory and use some sort of cursor? It seems result and result array are both arrays. (one is array of objects other is an array of arrays)

Comment: You can use [Pagination](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) with limit, i.e. `$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);`.

Comment: I was hoping not to do pagination, but I think I will have to do that for large queries in the future.

Comment: Can't you just use the limit clause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Active Record, which I would personally recommend, `limit()` should achieve what you are looking for.

`$this->db->limit();`

**Can also use in this way**, *slightly easier and less lines of code*:

```
$query = $this->db->get('Table_Name', 50); //syntax db->get('Table',limit_val);
return $query->result();
```

**Also** can return a limit with an offset:

```
$this->db->limit(10, 20); // Second parameter lets you set a result offset
```

**Link for more help on Active Record Query's**
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 2):

Mysql offset is the pointer you are looking for. 
You can use it like:

```
    $this->db->get(tableName,10,20);
```

The second parameter and the third one help you to set limit and offset .

[Here are more details](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)